# add context (this) to google maps request

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am developing this page for a site, that generates search results based on the current logged in user. My aim is to loop through every house and assign it a distance.

My issue is I cannot seem to use context (this) inside of a distance matrix request/response.

`$('.houseWrapper').each(function() {
    var origin = $(this).children('.houseMeta').attr('data-origin');
    var destination = $(this).children('.houseMeta').attr('data-destination');
    var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
    service.getDistanceMatrix({
        origins: [origin],
        destinations: [destination],
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
        unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
        avoidHighways: false,
        avoidTolls: false,
    }, callback);
    function callback(response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
            var origins = response.originAddresses;
            var destinations = response.destinationAddresses;
            for (var i = 0; i < origins.length; i++) {
                var results = response.rows[i].elements;
                for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {
                    var element = results[j];
                    var distance = element.distance.text;
                    var duration = element.duration.text;
                    console.log($(this).html());
                }
            }
        }
    }
});`

Answer (score 1):

try :

```
var that = this;
var origin = $(this).children('.houseMeta').attr('data-origin');
....
```

Then later:

```
console.log($(that).html());
```

Comment: Absolutely this works! This exactly was my work around. I was hoping there was a way to pass it through the request, like some kind of AJAX option.

Answer (score 0):

I would make "this" passed in as an argument to the function, kind of like how a partial function works.

```
var callback = function(this) {
    return function(response, status) {
        // ...
    }
}(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

there are 2 arguments that will be passed to the `$.each()`-callback, the index of the element and the element.

Just use these arguments:

```
$('.houseWrapper').each(function(index,node) {
   //somewhere
   console.log($(node).html());
});
```